# FTP sync only new files

Tags: php, ftp, synchronization

I have the following problem where I need to download to a local directory only new files from an FTP structure, process them using various PHP scripts, and then move them to an archive so they cannot be processed again.

The FTP structure is as follows:

- root
- root --2011
- root --2011 --12
- root --2011 --12 --01, 02 etc

It uses a separate folder for each folder structure. Once at day level, it then lists files that use  a time stamp naming convention.g. *2011-12-09-09-21-34-753.dat*

---

What I need to be able to do is ignore the folder structure on the FTP, download only new .dat files into a single 'local' folder for processing and ensure that these have not been downloaded before.

The files are text only and vary from 1kb to at worst 1.5mb. The FTP server is hosted on a Windows host.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use for rsync:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

The other way would be to manually log the files/dates you've processed before, and manually sync the changes.  I would use rsync personally.

Comment: I was under the impression that RSync does not work over FTP?

Comment: Couldn't you rcync to a temp folder remotely, then locally download just the temp folder?

Comment: Rsync works natively over a remote connection via SSH. If you have SSH access then that would work fine.

Comment: Should have added, the FTP server is a Windows 2008 host.

Comment: Best option seems to be rsync over ssh (@liquorvicars's suggestion).  I'm not too experienced with Windows servers, so idk if there's a better route specifically for Windows...

Comment: Can't install anything but FTP on the Windows server I'm afraid :(

Comment: You can't put ssh?  I think rsync could go on the local machine, so all you'd really need on the remote server is shell access...